# Nav_view not found on ROS diamondback

Tags: ros, visualization, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to install the nav_view package on ROS Diamondback on a 64 bit mac Snowleopard. However this is what I see,

j0813563:~ sagnikdhar$ rospack find nav_view
[rospack] couldn't find package [nav_view]

Has nav_view been deprecated ? If yes, what is the alternative package for Visualization applications ?

Thank you.

~ Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9195/nav_view-not-found-on-ros-diamondback/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this ros-users [email thread](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110209.000311.c0e99ca6.en.html). The relevant bit from that thread:

> So, for DTurtle, we're trying to remove dependencies on visualization stacks
> like ogre from our core stacks. Since navigation falls into this category,
> and the nav_view package relies on ogre, it has to move from navigation.
> That much is decided. However, I'm not sure exactly where to put the
> nav_view package. Do I create a new stack or just throw it in sandbox?

I'm not sure where it moved to, but I believe it has been deprecated in favor of using [rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-24**:
You can download the cturtle version of nav_view here: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/navigation/tags/cturtle/nav_view/